# What can we say about the differentiability of $f(z)= \Im(z)^n$ at $z=0$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

> What can we say about the differentiability of $f(z)= \Im(z)^n$ at $z=0$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$?

It is clear to me that $\Im(z)$ is not differentiable at $0$. This follows from the fact that for $\Re(z) \neq 0$, $\dfrac{\Im(z)}{z} = \dfrac{0}{z} = 0$ but for $z \neq 0$ purely imaginary, $\dfrac{\Im(z)}{z} = \dfrac{z}{z} = 1$

It is also clear to me that $\Im(z)^2$ is differentiable at $z=0$. I have come up with two different ways to arrive at this conclusion, one of them is the following:

Notice that $\displaystyle  \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{\Im(z)^2}{z} = 0$ if and only if $\displaystyle \left| \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{\Im(z)^2}{z}\right| = \lim_{z \to 0} \left|\frac{\Im(z)^2}{z}\right| =0$

Then, observe that, for $z \neq 0$, $$\left| \frac{\Im(z)^2}{z}\right| = \left|\frac{z^2 - 2z \bar{z} + \bar{z}^2 }{-4z}\right| \leq \frac{1}{4} \left(|z| + 2| - \bar{z} |+ \left|\frac{\bar{z}^2}{z}\right|\right)= \frac{1}{4}  \cdot 4|z| = |z| $$

With correct algebraic manipulation we can get from this inequality that $ \displaystyle \lim_{z \to 0} \left|\frac{\Im(z)^2}{z}\right| \leq \lim_{z \to 0} |z|$. Hence $\displaystyle \lim_{z \to 0} \left|\frac{\Im(z)^2}{z}\right|=0$.

Now I would like to find a way to determine the differentiability of $\Im(z)^n$ for arbitrary $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. I am fairly confident that I will be able to show that $\Im(z)^n$ is differentiable for $n \geq 2$. But for $n \leq -1$ I'm not sure what will happen.

Comment: How do you expect to differentiate at a point not in the domain of the function?

Answer (score 1):

$|\Im (z)| \leq |z|$.

So $\left|\frac {\Im(z)^{n}-0} z\right| \leq |z|^{n-1} \to 0$ as $z \to 0$ for any $n >1$.

The function is not even defined in any neighborhood of $0$ if $n <0$.

Comment: Thanks, I just realized this. Do you have a hint about the case when n is negative?

Comment: @LiamO'Brien It is not even defined in any neighborhood of $0$ if $n <0$.